# How to disable or hide submit button after form validate and submited by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, ecmascript-6

Need a script that `disable` or `hide` submit button after validating and 100% form submitted by `ajax`.

Current code:

```
<script>
    function AjaxFormRequest(result_id,formUkrposhta,url) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"html",
            data:jQuery("#"+formUkrposhta).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#messegeUkrResult").html('<span class="wbsn-padding-0">Секунду пожалуйста ...</span>');
                $("#send").prop('disabled', true); // disable button
            },
            success:function(response) {
                $("#send").prop('disabled', false); // enable button
                document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = response;

            },
            error: function(response) {
                document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = '<p class="wbsn-font-futuranew wbsn-font-20 wbsn-text-deep-orange" style="text-sahdow:0 2px 1px #fff;">Возникла ошибка при заказе. Попробуйте еще раз.</p>';
            }
         });

         $(':input', '#formUkrposhta')
            .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
            .val('')
            .removeAttr('checked')
            .removeAttr('selected');
    }
</script>
```

But nothing happened! And button not `disabled` after `success` send. Even more... need `submit` button hiding after 100% `success` sending and after treatmenting by php script (not after error or another)... Sorry for my bad English and many thanks to all. Let the power be with you!

Comment: it looks like you are disabling the button when you initiate the ajax, and enabling it on return.  Does the response get put into the element? Is this a simple case of it happening so fast you do not see it?  Using Chrome you can introduce lag if required.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: you can use onclick() instead of onsubmit(). I think your problem will solve with onclick()

Comment: @mahdikhodabandello... not interesting your example, because it's disabled even form have errors

Comment: @Twisty... everything ok... no error..

Comment: So, you need to enable the button if there are errors OR it was successful?

Comment: @Steve0... i need that button hide after 100% success submition and didn't show, only after user page reload. Simply said... only one success submit per user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider this code:

```
function AjaxFormRequest(result_id,formUkrposhta,url) {
  console.log("Ajax Form Request Triggered.");
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: jQuery("#" + formUkrposhta).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log("Before Send Triggered.");
      $("#messegeUkrResult").html('<span class="wbsn-padding-0">Секунду пожалуйста ...</span>');
      $("#send").prop('disabled', true); // disable button
    },
    success:function(response) {
      console.log("Success Triggered:", response);
      $("#send").prop('disabled', false).hide(); // enable button & Hide it
      $("#" + result_id).html(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      console.log("Error Triggered:", response);
      $("#" + result_id).html('<p class="wbsn-font-futuranew wbsn-font-20 wbsn-text-deep-orange" style="text-sahdow:0 2px 1px #fff;">Возникла ошибка при заказе. Попробуйте еще раз.</p>');
    }
  });
  $(':input', '#formUkrposhta')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');
}
```

This adds `.hide()` to the button in `success`.

Comment: sorry.. but nothing happend

Comment: BEST... But button hide even form error... and it shy(( you can see it here: http://nirvana.ho.ua/coffee/?vichy=upst#zakaz ... you can click on button even if form is empty and it will hide (

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет I see 2 Errors in Console: *TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined[Learn More] flyeing.buttons.and.scroll.js:232:1 <anonymous> http://nirvana.ho.ua/coffee/js/flyeing.buttons.and.scroll.js:232:1* And: *ReferenceError: domReady is not defined[Learn More] preloader.js:4:405 <anonymous> http://nirvana.ho.ua/coffee/js/preloader.js:4:405* Yet this function is working as expected, Ajax is triggered and button is hidden as you requested. If you need to perform validation, you will need to add that.

Comment: add what? sorry i can't see

Comment: about console error... if you see up button and left right flyeing buttons - so everything is good.